# SERP is just showing the main page but none of the subpages

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo, google-search

Have a look on [**this search**](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:arda-maps.org%20-arda-maps.org%2FForum) where you can see that just my main page is indexed.

But why does Google/Search engines not take **arda-maps.org/about/** and the other subpages? Is my deep linking done in a wrong way? Do the search engines need more time? If they do need more time why is the forum - which came very late - already indexed?

And by clicking the links I'm loading the "subpages" via **hiding** and **showing** of **layers**. Maybe it's because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see index-follow tag in your html code. It's better to have it

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

Also you can do two more things. Go to GWT > Crawl > Fetch as Google and submit some of your pages. Also click on the Sitemaps button in the left menu and submit your sitemap. 
Also you can share pages from your site in Twitter or Google+, everything posted there is indexed very fast.

Wish you luck,
Kasmetski

Comment: Thanks, added now the about page. Let's see if this is soon added to the search. I also added the meta statement. But I already had the sitemap added in GWT. Also gonna try to share the page, kind of the last thing I can do I believe.

Comment: Wow that manual adding see to be helping. I added the about page in GWT, and now one day later that page is finally in Google. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a `robots.txt`. It is always good idea to implement one. This might explain your issue, because when Google does not find one it stops crawling websites. Check for warnings or error messages in Google Webmaster Tools.

I have also seen that `site:arda-maps.org` returns urls with `www`. You should implement a redirect from `www` to `non-www` URLs.

Keep in mind that the `site` command does not return all indexed pages.

Your About page does not have a `NOINDEX` tag which is good. I have noticed you have a `sitemap.xml` and that your About page is in there. If the issue persists, this probably means Google thinks your page is not worth indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the good points. Well the www entries are from adding the www... page instead of the non-www version. That was a mistake of mine. I now declared the non-www as main page and in some days Google should update this. Afaik you just need a robots.txt when you want to exclude pages from the SERP or generally to be indexed, isn't that correct? I don't think this has negative influence or any effect on my issue. The idea about Google thinking it's not worth, well, that's very poor if these really important subpages are less important than forum entries.

Comment: Can I somewhere see in the webmaster tools how many sites are indexed? I mean there just seem to be indexed one site. But that cannot be as the forum should also count into this. Is there anything I can do to speed up the reindexing. Do you know any mechanic?

Comment: You need a robots.txt to index pages. If you submit your sitemap in GWT, it will tell you how many pages are indexed. Google will process your pages quickly. Use a recent lastmod value.

Comment: Alright added the robots.txt now. =) But in GWT I can't see anything about the indexing of subpages. So I need to wait for Google now I believe. Thank you anyway, I will come back here when I have new information.

Comment: Found out that Google does not support the DC. So thats the reason for no changes... scholar.google.dk/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing